# FormData passing objects in ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, form-data

I work on a project requiring ajax requests to read it in php.

I am using FormData to pass my values in ajax and I am unable to embed an array of objects, here is the code:

```
function create_message(){  

    //My Array
    var recipients = [];
    var recipient = {lastname:"dupont",firstname:'chris',email:"email@email.fr"};
    recipients.push(recipient);
    recipients.push(recipient);

    var form_data = new FormData();    

    form_data.append('recipients', JSON.stringify(recipients));//stringify my array
    form_data.append('file_picture', file_picture);
    form_data.append('file_video', file_video);
    form_data.append('file_audio', file_audio);
    form_data.append('programming', jQuery("#form_message #date-message").val());
    form_data.append("message", jQuery("#form_message #message-message").val());
    form_data.append("action", 'create_message');
                        
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(context){
            var data = JSON.parse(context);
            if(data.response === 'ok'){
                
            } 
        }
     });
}
```

PHP code:

```
function create_message_ajax(){
    $recipients = json_decode($_POST['recipients'],true); //my array
    $programming = sanitize_text_field($_POST['programming']); 
    $message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']);
    $file_picture_handler = 'file_picture';
    $file_video_handler = 'file_video';
    $file_audio_handler = 'file_audio';


    $context['recipients'] = $recipients;
    $context['response'] = 'ok';
    echo json_encode($context);
    wp_die();
}
```

My query returns null on this variable (recipients) :

[image]

I really don't know why the php can't read my table and I need to keep FormData for sending my files (image, video, audio)

Thank you !

[EDIT]

Test with print_r on $_POST :

```
Array
(
    [recipients] => [{\"lastname\":\"dupont\",\"firstname\":\"chris\",\"email\":\"email@email.fr\"},{\"lastname\":\"dupont\",\"firstname\":\"chris\",\"email\":\"email@email.fr\"}]
    [file_picture] => 
    [file_video] => 
    [file_audio] => 
    [programming] => 
    [message] => 
    [action] => create_message
)
```

[EDIT 2 SOLVED]

you have to add the following code:

```
$_POST['recipients'] = str_replace('\\', '', $_POST['recipients']);
$recipients = json_decode($_POST['recipients'],true);
```

Comment: Start you debugging by doing a `print_r($_POST)` and looking at what is actually getting passed to you

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly and thank you for you help. print_r on $_POST return : 

Array
(
    [recipients] => [{\"lastname\":\"dupont\",\"firstname\":\"chris\",\"email\":\"email@email.fr\"},{\"lastname\":\"dupont\",\"firstname\":\"chris\",\"email\":\"email@email.fr\"}]
    [file_picture] => 
    [file_video] => 
    [file_audio] => 
    [programming] => 
    [message] => 
    [action] => create_message
)

Comment: Why are you pushing the same data twice to your `recipients`-array?

Comment: Hello ! It's just for test

Comment: No the $context['response'] = 'ok'; is for the front return. The print_r is what the php receives

Comment: Silly me, so it is :)

Comment: The JSON is considered invalid. To make it valid I had to do `$_POST['recipients'] = str_replace('\\', '', $_POST['recipients']);` before decoding it.

Comment: All those escaped double quotes make your JSON invalid. Not exactly clear where those would be coming from, with the code you have shown so far (magic quotes have been removed in PHP a long time ago, not sure if FormData would be adding those in here?), but if you apply `stripslashes` to the value before you decode it as JSON, it should work.

Comment: FormData wouldn't add them. Magic Quotes and a dire, dire need to upgrade to a supported version of PHP would be my first guess. Otherwise maybe some non-built-in other ill-conceived filter that tries to prevent XSS on input instead of output?

Comment: Ok it works  with : str_replace('\\', '', $_POST['recipients']); 
thank you all ! :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly — It will convert to `"[object Object]"`. Form data doesn't do implicit JSON conversion.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, was a bit of a stab in the dark. I should know better really